# Post current time of comment

Tags: php, mysql, time, timestamp, comments

Im trying to get my commentbox to post the current time after the comment, but the old comments keep changing time to the current time. I want it to show the time of the post and i dont know how to do.

```
$date = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));


echo $name . '<br/>' . '<br/>' . $comment . $date->format('d-m-Y H:i:s') . '<br/>' . '<br/>' . '<hr size="1"/>'
```

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of `DateTime()` needs to be the date of the comment. If it always says "now" it will always be the current date/time.

Assuming you called the row from your database query `$row` and the column in the database is called `datefromdatabase` your code would look like this:

```
$date = new DateTime($row['datefromdatabase'], new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
```